# Activity Indicator show and hide in splash Image  & UITableView

Tags: iphone

i want to  add activity indicator & show at when i select didSelectRowAtIndexPath and hide at while detailView page displayed...plz help anyone.... and Give any sample Code.

Comment: can u please elaborate your scenario.Your question title doesnot match ur problem

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)showActivityViewer {
self.activityView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.window.bounds.size.width, self.view.window.bounds.size.height)] autorelease];
activityView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
activityView.alpha = 0.5;

self.activityWheel = [[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(self.view.window.bounds.size.width / 2 - 12, self.view.window.bounds.size.height / 2 - 12, 24, 24)] autorelease];
activityWheel.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
activityWheel.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin |
                                  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin |
                                  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin |
                                  UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin);
[activityView addSubview:activityWheel];
[self.view.window addSubview: activityView];
[[[activityView subviews] objectAtIndex:0] startAnimating];
}

-(void)removeActivityViewer {
[activityWheel removeFromSuperview];
[activityView removeFromSuperview];
self.activityWheel = nil;
self.activityView = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MBProgressHUD does exactly that! Check out https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD